# How can I convert all e-mail address of page into image in php?

Tags: php, image, email

I want to convert all email address of page into image so that robots cant copy that.

Comment: Take a look at this [php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php)

Comment: yes this function is very useful.

now how can i detect all email address present on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could find DaftLogic useful library for the convertion: [DaftLogic](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-text-to-image.htm)